# Javascript toggle using custom attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can't seem to get this to work for me, can anyone offer me some help?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kABjC

This should open and close a section of text based on click, it takes the ID # which is just a digit (1,2,3,4,etc) and using that id targets an id to open and close the section.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.classclick').click(function(){
   $('#class'+$(this).Attr('data-id')+"show").show(400); 
   });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="classes">
    <?php foreach ($classes as $class): ?>
        <div class="class">
            <div class="classclick" data-id="<?=$class['cid']?>">
                <div class="class-title">
                    <?=$class['className']?>
                </div>
                <div class="class-intensity">
                    Intensity: <?=$class['classIntensity']?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="class-show hidden" id="class<?=$class['cid']?>show">
                <div class="class-inner-content">
                    <div class="two-thirds">
                        <?=$class['classDesc']?>    </div>
                    <div class="one-third">
                        Things To Know:
                        asdfasd
                        asdf
                        afsdadfs

                        fsda
                        dfsa
                        dfsadfsa
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `.attr` not `.Attr`, note you could also use the [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method since you are using a data-* attribute, your actual code at codepen doesnt work because you havent included jquery

Comment: switching it to .attr('data-id') does not work, neither does .data('id') or .data('data-id')

Comment: because as i said you didnt include jquery: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kLitu

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fx7jdLb4/1/) - The `.hidden` element is next in the dom, try using [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to select `.hidden` and toggling it.

```
$('.classclick').click(function(){
   $(this).next(".hidden").toggle(400);
});
```

This avoids string concatenation, each loops & extra selectors while making it more readable for you.

Answer (score 1):

as Patrick suggested, You might have missed the jQuery inclusion in CodePen, but i would suggest using $.each when using a class selector. [Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egJIo)

```
$('.classclick').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
   $('#class'+$(this).data('id')+"show").toggle(400); 
  });
});
```